# Openfire Rest API plugin field Authorization

Tags: rest, http-headers, openfire, response-headers

I have a problem. I'm trying to get access to Openfire Rest API plugin via **https** in this way:

```
https://my-openfire.org.ua:7443/http-bind/plugins/restapi/v1/chatrooms
```

And I get error:

> Failed to load https://my-openfire.org.ua:7443/http-bind/plugins/restapi/v1/chatrooms: Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

People, what am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please help me o this, I am getting the following :--- Access to fetch at 'http://192.168.5.237:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users/test1' from origin 'http://169.254.129.32:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the path: https://myopenfire.org.ua:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/chatrooms

(It uses the web interface port) and it's not binded to "http-bind"

Comment: S Access to fetch at 'http://192.168.5.237:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users/test1' from origin 'http://169.254.129.32:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: take the latest rest api plugin. We had some problems with CORS in the past

Comment: I download and replace the restAPI.jar having version 1.3.7. But the same issue

Comment: I've downgraded the plugin to v 1.3.1. and got the same corse error.